# React Navigation: Re-render causes navigation ref.current to be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use react-navigation make a reusable SplitView component for React Native where the parent navigators are able to perform navigations on their children. To accomplish this I am using ref's to programmatically perform navigations on nested navigators. However, I am running into an issue where when my app re-renders, all my navigation refs become:

```
{ current: null }
```

And I am not able to perform any further navigations.

Here is a link to a [Snack project](https://snack.expo.io/@alexho/splitview-nav-bug) demonstrating this issue. Note that you will have to uncomment lines 13-17 in `App.js` to see the issue. The commented-out useEffect is there to force an initial re-render. Without it the navigation works just fine.

The docs for ["Navigating without the navigation prop"](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization) have some notes around initialization issues with this use case but I didn't have any luck with their suggested solutions. I think the issue they are referring to is a race condition before the Navigation container has a chance to mount--I don't think this is what is happening to me because it seems like once my app re-renders I NEVER get access to the correct ref.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the issue was because I was using `createRef` instead of `useRef`. When working with refs + functional components it's necessary to use the `useRef` hook since `createRef` will return a new ref on every render, and it's not possible to store the created ref as an instance variable as you would in a class component.